# SQL Server error 'Cannot find data type'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm getting this error message when saving/updating a table from c#.

> Column, parameter, or variable #6: Cannot find data type MyDataType.

`User defined data-type MyDataType is numeric(18,2)`

Everything worked OK before re-installing the machine where the SQL Server 2008 was installed.

Already tried setting compatibility_level, but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [re-create the type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx):

```
create type MyDataType from numeric(18,2) not null
```

Comment: I've got to many dependencies to this user defined type, can't re-create it.